# Android Paging Library - Map Room DataSource.Factory<*, DatabaseModel> to DataSource.Factory<*, PresenterModel>

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack, android-paging, android-paging-library

I use two models in my app:

1. Database
2. Presenter (UI)

Android Paging gives me a `DataSource.Factory<*, DatabaseModel>`

```
@Dao
interface ProjectDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM project")
    fun getAllProjects(): DataSource.Factory<Int, DatabaseModel>
    ...
}
```

When I want to make the `LiveData` using `LivePagedListBuilder(dataSourceFactory, config)` I need to map:

`DataSource.Factory<*, DatabaseModel>` -|----> `DataSource.Factory<*, PresenterModel>`

Is there any way possible to achieve this. I'm also open to here any approach done using RxKotlin (RxJava).

Comment: how you have bind the data to recycle view ? Are you using binding adapter for it ?

Comment: @Abdul I use `submitList` function in my observer inside the `Fragment` that observes it. I want to know is there any way to map database to the UI model.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is how i have done done it

Data Source

```
fun getDataSource(): DataSource.Factory<Int, DBModel> {
     return database.dao.getAllData()
   }
```

variable at view model

```
val scannedCompleteList=App.getRepository().getDataSource().toLiveData(
                Config(
                    pageSize = 60,
                    enablePlaceholders = true,
                    maxSize = 200
                )
            )
```

Now i have a binding adapter where i convert the data from db model to domain model

```
@BindingAdapter("setData")
fun setImageScanned(recyclerView: RecyclerView, data: List<DBModel>?) {
        val adapter = recyclerView.adapter as MyAdapter
        adapter.submitList(it.asDomainModel())
    }
}
```

So you are observing data at fragment so you can convert the data to presenter inside observer.
asDomainModel is an extension function which do the conversion

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate this. I will mark you as the correct answer if nothing better comes up.

Comment: that will be great.

Comment: this is a bad solution. The UI should never even get a DBModel